# How to POST multiple data in DRF and React with Axios

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models named Recipe and Step..
I have serialized both to make an API for GET request.. I want to know is there a way to create for POST request so that I can send both the data (steps and recipe) in the same request?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    uuid = models.CharField( max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.uuid}'
    

class Step(models.Model):
    step = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    uuid = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.step} - {self.uuid}'
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'uuid']


class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = ['step', 'uuid']
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import *
from .models import *

@api_view(['GET'])
def apiOverview(request):
    api_urls = {
        'List':'/recipe-list/',
        'Detail View':'/recipe-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Create':'/recipe-create/',
        'Update':'/recipe-update/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete':'/recipe-delete/<str:pk>/',
        'Steps' : '/steps/<str:pk>'
    }
    return Response(api_urls)


@api_view(['GET'])
def recipeList(request):
    recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer = RecipeSerializer(recipes, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def recipeDetail(request, pk):
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(uuid=pk)
    recipe_serializer = RecipeSerializer(recipe, many=False)
    steps = Step.objects.filter(uuid=pk)
    steps_serializer = StepSerializer(steps, many=True)
    return Response({
        'recipe' : recipe_serializer.data,
        'steps' : steps_serializer.data
    })
```

How can I create a view for POST and handle both the models?

Comment: Yes you can. Just put them in one request data, and have a serializer that uses both `RecipeSerializer` and `StepSerializer`. Although whether this approach is best practice or not is another discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import *


class StepAndRecipe(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Step.objects.all()
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StepSerializer
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
```

Add in urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import StepAndRecipe

urlpatterns = [
    path('steprecipepost', StepAndRecipe.as_view(), name='steps_recipes')
```

This will only work with POST! And one more thing: take care with the raw data and the HTML form, maybe theses get a little confused since you are using two models in the same view.

Comment: Is it possible to have it combined in the same class?

I don't want to make 2 different POST requests from react to POST the data separately..

Comment: I would like to have both the recipe and the step at the same view and url to POST and GET.. Hope I am clear